# searchBar.rx.textDidBeginEditing does not working when im trying to edit text

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

```
    searchBar.rx.textDidBeginEditing
        .subscribe { [unowned self] in
            print("im begining diting")
            self.searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

It does not working, maybe I have wrong method? but I have method

```
    searchBar.rx.text
        .asObservable()
        .bind(to: directoryViewModel.searchTextObservable)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Its working properly

Comment: You haven't shown enough code to reproduce the problem. If I put those two blocks of code in a viewDidLoad, they work exactly as expected.

Comment: what should I show? cause the second block works fine, but the first one doesn't want to call.

Comment: Are you getting any runtime warnings from the console? Have you assigned a delegate to the searchBar? You show a minimum *compilable* example that exhibits the problem. Write a small project the the least code possible that still has the problem you are seeing.

Comment: I don't get no runtime warnings and no I didn't assigned to delegate. I wrote a small project but the same problem, probably I just don't know how to use this

Comment: I'd love to see the project. Maybe I can figure out what's going on.

Comment: I figured out) but tnx anyway!)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I forgot to put onNext:

```
searchBar.rx.textDidBeginEditing
.subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] in

    self.searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)

}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: That's not the reason it was failing. There was something else wrong.

Comment: Why not? It works fine now, just set asObservable() and subscribe(onNext:)

Comment: Because if `asObservable()` was necessary, then the code wouldn't have even _compiled_ without it.